# IPFS. Add a directory recursively with an HTTP api

Tags: blockchain, ipfs

Is there an [HTTP api](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/http/) equivalent of doing:

```
ipfs add -r resources/public
```

where `resources/public` is a directory with a static website (index.html in the root, css, js etc).

Doing:

```
 curl -F file=resources/public/index.html "http://$IPFS_HOST:5001/api/v0/add?recursive=true&wrap-with-directory=true"
```

Will only upload one file:

```
{"Name":"index.html","Hash":"QmZzbCaCPMEGJBLv7DJCDD2mvgkrvTg78MXYt7cPrQhge6","Size":"1255"}
{"Name":"","Hash":"QmdAGnATEQ1VoytC8L9h5nNepmiZCXv61ob49Dpz5nZVGf","Size":"1312"}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not yet good enough to be the "answer" but this should get you much closer than the existing answers. It's not pretty, but will upload a small directory.  It also doesn't work with filenames/dirs that have spaces. I'll update this answer if I am able to improve it.

Is this example we use ipfs.infura.io

```sh
cd /your/chosen/path

FILES=$(find * -type f | grep -v ' ' | awk -v q="'" '{print " -F " q "file=@\"" $0 "\";filename=\"" $0 "\"" q}')

curl "https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/add?pin=true&recursive=true&wrap-with-directory=true" -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" $FILES
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem. I could be wrong, but this is presently not possible to do with Curl. I believe you can use the API inside a Javascript application to upload a path recursively, but with Curl you can only attach a single file, there is no recursive function built in for uploading directories.

If you find a solution do please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use infura [ipfs-upload-client](https://github.com/INFURA/ipfs-upload-client) which is designed for exactly that and very straightforward

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a website in IPFS in its entirety as long as it is static from my understanding.

Parallax websites with anchor links work wonders.

Just do this:

ADD TO IPFS:
1) ipfs add -r [ directory where web files are located ]

PIN IT SO IT DOESN'T DISAPPEAR FROM YOUR NODE IF YOUR DAEMON IS NOT ON:
2) ipfs pin add -r [IPFS hash from above]
          -Side Note: Make sure you copy the last hash to pin since that will be your 
           root directory

TEST IT ON YOUR NODE:
3) http://localhost:port/ipfs/[IPFS hash]

It should work.

Here is an example of a demo parallax website I uploaded to IPFS.  I'm using my own node as a gateway, not the default IPFS gateway:

http://mymobiservices.com:9001/ipfs/QmbaE6vj8xq2inkx5km7stKX3GSjeeKYt2QmB7opNXJhCB

Hope this answers your question.  If you need help, let me know.

I'm still learning IPFS so bear with me as I may not know everything related to it.

Pavon